# git svn error zlib decompression file too large

Tags: git, svn, zlib

I am attempting to shift my svn repo to git, and I am using git svn to clone the original repo. Everything seemed to be working, but I encountered this error:

```
Svndiff compressed data is invalid: Decompression of zlib compressed data failed: size too large at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 312.
```

Unsure it didn't have to do with space/RAM limitations on my computer I tried it on a larger one and got the same error.

I'm relatively new to this and gotten where I am mostly through some good internet searching with trial and error.

1. How do I identify the actual problem
2. How do I fix it (I am pretty sure I can't just delete the revision files causing the issue - That would be bad...)

Comment: Everything I've been able to find about that error suggests that it's due to a corrupted subversion repository. Can you successfully dump the repository (using `svnadmin dump` or `svnrdump`) and load it into a new repository using `svnadmin load`?

Comment: Bummer, but thanks! ... I'll have to play around with those commands and see. I consider myself beyond noob level with these things so I'll probably be doing a fair amount more research / learning :)